# Heat issues: Shall I replace the case or its fans?

Tags: freeze, cooling

I've been having frequent OS freezing issues with my new PC for a while, and for some reason the problem disappeared (or so it seems) when I opened my desktop's case (even though it's an aluminum case with 3 fans in it as you can see here: http://www.overclock.co.uk/product/Thermaltake-LanBox-VF1000SWA-Silver-Gaming-Cube,-No-PSU_151.html )

First of all, would heat cause such an issue with the OS? if so, do I need to get a bigger case or better fans? if it's the latter, then should I look for in the new fans?

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heat can cause any and every sort of problem. It is possible that the airflow is not good.

I would recommend that you test the flow to make sure that the air is going all in one direction and not everything pointing in or out.

If it works when the case is off, upgrading the fans to better/faster ones should do the trick.

The problem with little cases is that (especially if you use high end components) the parts that would normally be spread out are very close to each other - The hard drive, optical drive, gpu, chipset and cpu are all within a few CM of each other.

At the end of the day, if you went for a little case because you move around a lot, I recommend upgrading the fans. If you bought this because it looked cool (which I know a lot of people do!) but stay in one place all the time, it may be cheaper for you to buy a budget standard full size case and transfer the components over.

Comment: Thanks for your informative response. How do I test the airflow though? Also, do you think if I got a cheaper GPU (since the nvidia 8800 GT i have averages at 61C) would keep the case cooler?

Comment: That opening statement is ever so true, +1.

Comment: @Unknown - there are a variety of ways to test air flow, my personal favourite is to get a single piece of toilet paper and separate the layers so you have a very thin sheet, then assuming you have a dust cover or similar (such as punched out holes on the case) put it against it - if it sticks, you have an intake, if it falls - you have a blower / outtake. You can do something similar with a small piece of string - just be careful you don't let it go in and clog up the fan!